# Spark SQL Result Set

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to get a result set of a Spark Sql job from an Application (say a Java based Program).

The Java Program submits a Spark SQL Job and has to get back the result set and do some processing (save to db etc) on it

Comment: I am wondering do you really need it!! We use spark to deal with huge date sets. When you say resultset you are trying to get everything to single Machine(JVM) which obviously lead to OOM errors. Is that what you need?. But you can directly write data to different destinations from Spark.

Comment: You can just write any program, that will be executed on a driver, with any kind of processing and saving results to db. If you want Spark to do some calculations, which, for instance, would result in small enough data, that it would fit on the driver - just go for it, submit your job using SparkContext, then `collect` the result, and process it further on Driver.

Comment: So my use case is something like this. I have a multi-tenant Microservice which has to do some aggregations based on some changes to the data triggered by a tenant action. The aggregated data needs to be exposed via a REST API. The idea is to do the aggregations and be able to save them in my DB in the Microservice. With a DataWarehouse like Google Big Query, we can get the result set back and store the data required in a synchronous call. I am looking for something similar; invoke a Spark SQL job and get the result set and save it in my DB